# MS Access - Link two fields in one table

Tags: ms-access, vba, relationship

**In Advance:**
I have two tables, *Einnahmen* and *Personen*. Each person in *Personen* has a name and an abbreviation. These two fields are also present and linked in *Einnahmen*. Here you can see the relationship of the two tables.

[image: relationship]

**Onto my question:** Is it possible to have the corresponding value appear if I enter just one. So for example if I enter the abbreviation, I want the corresponding name to be entered and if I enter the name I want the corresponding abbreviation to appear.

**Why?** The abbreviations solely exists to make form inputs easier and faster. This is especially used in this [image: subform]. As you can see both the name and abbreviation are visible and if I choose either of them the other one should update accordingly.

If you want to have a look at the tables:

Table Einnahmen:

[image: Einnahmen]

Table Personen:

[image: Personen]

Comment: Your data model is wrong. Table Personen needs a PK (Primary Key), I would suggest an Auto-Increment. Persons names are not always unique (think of Müller in germany). That PK should be stored as FK (Foreign Key) in table Einnahmen. Then you can bind the comboboxes to the FK and display the wanted column (Person for the first, Kuerzel for the second one) by using different queries for the `RowSource`. If you change one of them the FK changes and the other one will reflect that. (after `Me.refresh' )

Comment: Kuerzel would need to be unique also, for it to find just one name and populate the Person box.  If not unique Kuerzel, then the subform would need to display a sub-sub form listing all the Person-s having the entered Keurzel, and allow user to select the "right" Person.

Comment: @donPablo if `Kürzel` isn't unique, you could display the name column too in `Kürzel`-Combo, but of course it should be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database schema should look like this, where the primary key `PersonID` could by an AutoNumber field:

[image: Database SChema]

In your form, you can use 2 comboboxes, both bound to the foreign key field `PersonID` but with different lookup queries:

[image: Design View]

```
SELECT Personen.PersonID, Personen.Person FROM Personen ORDER BY Personen.Person;
SELECT Personen.PersonID, Personen.Kürzel FROM Personen ORDER BY Personen.Kürzel;
```

If one of the 2 comboboxes is used to select a Person, the other one is updated accordingly:

[image: Immediate Update]